# Convert a list into a dictionary of list in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to convert a list into a dictionary in Python.

The list is:

```
list = [['a','aa','aaa'],['b','bb','bbb']]
```

And I want to convert it to a dictionary such that:

```
dictionary = {'aaa': ['a','aa'], 'bbb': ['b','bb']]
```

I'm looking for a variant of:

```
d = {i:j for i,j in list}
```

Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With list slicing, where `[-1]` grabs the last element of the list, and `[:-1]` grabs all elements up to the last:

Try refraining from using `list` as a variable name, since it is a built-in type:

```
d = {x[-1]: x[:-1] for x in lst}
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse ! Simple and effective!